# NOT NULL constraint failed: spring_post.publisher_id

Tags: python, django, create-view

I created a class base create view.When i try to submite the post model create view. it will return
**NOT NULL constraint failed: spring_post.publisher_id**
how can i set the publisher the get the current logged in user and set it to the post piblisher field.
im a beginner
this is the publisher field in my post model

```
    publisher=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
#and this is my views
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model=Post
    fields=['title','description']
    redirect_field_name="login"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `.publisher` of the post, so:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model=Post
    fields = ['title','description']
    redirect_field_name = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.publisher = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

You probably should also specify the [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) to specify where to redirect to if the POST request was successful.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).